# Removing the confidential message from a sharepoint site?

Tags: sub-site

Currently every time we open the homepage of a parent/ sub-site we receive this message as seen in the attached screenshot.

Assuming this is something that is configurable OOTB, is there a way to disable it?

[image]

Comment: It is looks like a custom code.
It appears only on home page of subsite? or on other pages too ?
If it appearing only on home page check content of this page and maybe there are some Custom Actions on that page.

Comment: Yeah it only appears on the home page or subsite home page. Any other pages we add (wiki's etc...) it doesnt appear. How do you check the custom actions of the page? Using SharePoint Online, I can only put the page into edit mode, can't even check the properties

Answer (score 0):

Do you use custom master page or standard?  If custom - check scripts inside master page.
Check source code of all web parts(content editor and script editor) on home page.
Try to rename homepage.
Try to open browser developer console and analyze what classes and id's are set to this block.